# Assign order variable by SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like as below, by using SAS, I need to assign the order variable based on descending count order to this dataset, when the category is missing, it should be always in the last whatever the count is. All other category above the missing one should be order by descending count.

Category           Count

```
aa               10

bb                9

cc                8

                  6

ab                3
```

Desired output:

Category           Count         Order

```
aa                    10                1

bb                      9                2

cc                      8                3

ab                      3                4

                         6                5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Proc DS2` to compute a sequence number for a result set.

Example:

```
data have;
input s $ f;
datalines;
aa 10
bb  9
cc  8
.   6
ab  3
;

proc ds2;
  data want(overwrite=yes);
    declare int sequence ;
    method run();
      set 
        {
          select s,f from have
          order by case when s is not null then f else -1e9-f end desc
        };
      sequence + 1;
    end;
  run;
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool solution!

Answer (score 0):

Sort and split all the datasets into descending value order by missing and not-missing category, then stack them on top of each other.

```
/* Sort the non-missing values */
proc sort data=have out=have_notmissing;
    by descending value;
    where NOT missing(category);
run;

/* Sort the missing values */
proc sort data=have out=have_missing;
    by descending value;
    where missing(category);
run;

/* Stack them on top of each other */
data want;
    set have_notmissing
        have_missing
    ;

    rank+1;
run;
```

Output:

```
category    value   rank
aa          10      1
bb          9       2
cc          8       3
ab          3       4
            6       5
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you really want is a NOTSORTED format and a procedure that supports the PRELOADFMT option and ORDER=DATA.

```
data test;
   input category $ count;
   cards;
aa               10
bb                9
cc                8
.                 6
ab                3
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;

proc format;
   value $cat(notsorted)
      'bb'='Bee Bee'
      'aa'='Aha'
      'cc'='CC'
      'dd'='D D'
      'ab'='AB'
      ;
   quit;
proc summary data=test nway missing;
   class category / order=data preloadfmt;
   format category $cat.;
   freq count;
   output out=summary(drop=_type_) / levels;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]